# The average number of characters per word in each paragraph? in an excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, function

In excel, if you have a cell containing a paragraph of information, how do you find the average of the word length in the cell?

The average number of characters per word in each paragraph, within an excel cell.

Example:

CELL A1: Mary has a little lamb

The average word length would be 3.6 characters/letters per word, doing it manually counting of course. If you have a large amount of text, that is quite difficult.

Does anyone know how to do this as a function?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))/(1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))
```

but this relies on spaces delimiting a "word" so might not work for all data.

Answer (score 1):

The trim function removes all spaces between words so the following should work:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))/(LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)
```

So the denominator will get you the # of words irrespective of how many additional spaces there might be between words.